# Design a compliance content search in O365 to ONLY return a specific person and a specific domain

Tags: microsoft-office-365, search, exchangeonline, office365, compliance

I am attempting to do a content search through Exchange on O365 to return mail between **user@domain.com** and anyone at **outsidedomain.com**

I thought that this should work in the KQL:

```
(ParticipantDomains:outsidedomain.com) AND ((Sender:user@domain.com) OR (Recipients:user@domain.com))
```

However, this seems to include all mail to/from user@domain.com

- No matter who it is sent from/to
- Also if user@domain.com is in a group to whom it was sent.

What do I need to put, to only find direct email conversations between user@domain.com and anyone at outsidedomain.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggested answer, from outside this site was the following:

```
((senderauthor=user@domain.com) AND (Participants=outsidedomain.com) OR 
(Recipients=user@domain.com) AND (Participants=outsidedomain.com))
```

This appears to result in the data I was looking for.

Comment: Great to see that you've got the answer that works for your situation : ) Thanks for the share!

Answer (score 0):

> Also if user@domain.com is in a group to whom it was sent.

To the best of my knowledge, it's not feasible to exclude this kind of mails from the results. A thought is to export the search result report file (.csv), open it in Excel to filter out mails sent to groups.

> However, this seems to include all mail to/from user@domain.com
>
> No matter who it is sent from/to

Although "participantdomains" looks like the most suitable property for your requirement, I cannot find any introduction about it in [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/ediscovery-keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?view=o365-worldwide). Also based on my test, I can reproduce that all mails would be included in the result when using "ParticipantDomains:outsidedomain.com".

Given this situation, I'd suggest using *Partifipants:"outsidedomain.com"* instead. You can choose to search within the user@domain.com's Exchange mailbox only so that no other conditions need to be included in the query.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.   It's frustrating that the participantsdomain LOOKS good but isn't.

I can't just search in the user's mailbox because they are gone and the mail exists in this strange "hold state" without a mailbox from what I can gather.  Will have a look again, this morning.